# Can't run/install steam on ubuntu 18.04/ Nvidia

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dependencies, steam

I had previously managed to install and run steam with no issues on Ubuntu 18.04. However, after a game update I had to roll back the Nvidia driver to be able to play it. Some time passed(maybe a month or more) before I tried to launch steam again.
When I try to launch it from the Applications list nothing happens, when i try to launch it from a terminal with `steam` i get an command not found error.

I have tried several different Nvidia drivers and reverting back to the Nouveau Driver with no success so, I tried to reinstall. This returns the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 17.3) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libtxc-dxtn0:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried to install the dependant packages, all of which return a similar errors.

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix the broken dependencies.

I've uninstalled `sudo apt remove steam` which returns:

```
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 13 not to upgrade.
```

Here is the output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`

```
  Installed: 1:20.0~git191205111100.96aef08~b~padoka0
  Candidate: 1:20.0~git191209141100.86dfe92~b~padoka0
  Version table:
     1:20.0~git191209141100.86dfe92~b~padoka0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/mesa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:20.0~git191205111100.96aef08~b~padoka0 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:20.0~git191209141100.86dfe92~b~padoka0
  Version table:
     1:20.0~git191209141100.86dfe92~b~padoka0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/mesa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

I have tried every fix I have found online but i'm stuck, i've tried so many random commands now i've no idea what i've changed and am contemplating a factory reset. 
Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT

`sudo apt remove libgl1-mesa-dri` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kio : Depends: libkf5notifications5 (>= 4.96.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libkf5wallet-bin but it is not going to be installed
 libatk-wrapper-java-jni : Depends: libatk-wrapper-java (>= 0.33.3-20ubuntu0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1 : Depends: libglx0 (= 1.2.0-1~b~padoka0) but it is not going to be installed
 libglx-mesa0 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri but it is not going to be installed
 libkf5wallet5 : Depends: libkwalletbackend5-5 (= 5.44.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Output of `apt cache policy` is:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-umang-indicator-stickynotes,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Indicator Stickynotes,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-umang-indicator-stickynotes,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Indicator Stickynotes,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/mesa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-paulo-miguel-dias-mesa,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=padoka PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/mesa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-paulo-miguel-dias-mesa,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=padoka PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-graphics-drivers,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Proprietary GPU Drivers,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=Ubuntu,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Can you remove the `libgl1-mesa-dri` package ?

Comment: No, doesn't seem to want to that either(see above edit)

Comment: `apt-cache policy`please.

Comment: Thanks, have edited the question to include results.